# Accessor function taking a const arg but returning non const pointer in C

Tags: c, const-correctness

seeking some advice here.

I have a structure which contains a pointer to another structure, something like this:

```
struct item
{
    int type;
    struct user *owner;
};
```

I also have accessor functions, like this:

```
int item_get_type(const struct item * i);
struct user * item_get_owner(const struct item * i);
```

My question is about the second of these functions: Does this violate any rules or best practices with regard to the use of const?

The reason I use const here is to signify that the accessor function will not modify the structure passed in to it, but the caller is allowed to modify the returned structure. Am I better off dropping the const in the argument?

Comment: As said by @Graham below, what you're doing is absolutely fine. If your intention would have been to not allow the caller to modify the returned structure, the return type would have been `const struct user*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's absolutely fine, and it correctly indicates your stated intention.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, even if it is easy for a user to modify the structure it is still good to use `const` as it will help the compiler to optimize the code in the function. The compiler will know it never needs to modify the structure inside the function.